# Which of the following predicate logic statements is not valid?

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Consider $W$ is a predicate statement which does not contain any free variable.

$(A)\space\space \exists_x(P(x)\land W) \equiv \exists_xP(x) \land W$

$(B) \space\space \forall_x(P(x)\lor W) \equiv \forall_xP(x) \lor W$

$(C) \space\space\forall_x(P(X) \implies W) \equiv \forall_xP(X) \implies W $

$(D) \space\space\exists_x(P(X) \implies W) \equiv \forall_xP(X) \implies W $

I figured out that option $C$ is not valid logical statement.
But my sir have provided the answer as $D$.

**My reasoning for option C being not valid:**

consider $W$ is $false:$ Now LHS evaluates to false if there is at least one value of $x$ for which $P(x)$ evaluates to true. So in particular when there are some elements in domain for which $P(x)$ evaluates to true and there are some for which it evaluates to $false$ both side of statement does not match.

So, any body confirm whether my reasoning is correct or not(If not please provide reason)? Thanks.

Comment: (C) and (D) are both invalid.

Comment: Why $D$ is invalid. I strongly believe that it is valid. Can you please explain that?

Comment: Can't we use following deduction: $(\forall_xP(x) \implies W )\equiv (\lnot \forall_xP(x) \lor W) \equiv (\exists_x\lnot P(x) \lor W) \equiv (\exists_x(\lnot P(x) \lor W)) \equiv (\exists_x(P(x) \implies W))$

Comment: @asdf_06 Yes we can. (D) is valid; (C) is not.